# Paint program trouble

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a simple paint program in c# winforms. I am using a panel as the canvas and ellipses as the paintbrush. When the user clicks on the panel and moves the mouse, ellipses get drawn on the panel. However, when the user moves the mouse too fast while the mouse is down, the ellipses get drawn in fragments. By any chance does anyone know why the ellipses are drawn in fragments instead of a consecutive line?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DrawApplication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool flag = false;
    public bool f = false;
    Graphics g;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    private void mainPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {     
    }
    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;
    private void mainPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseX = e.X;
        mouseY = e.Y;
        flag = true;
    }        
    private void mainPanel_hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void drawEllipse(int x, int y)
    {
        SolidBrush h = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 10, 10);
        g = mainPanel.CreateGraphics();
        g.FillEllipse(h, rect);
    }
    private void mainPanel_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    private void mainPanel_move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if(flag){
        drawEllipse(mouseX, mouseY);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, CreateGraphics.  You have to draw in the paint event of the panel (which means recording your mouse movements) or paint in a graphic object from a bitmap.  Lots of hits on this subject at StackOverflow.

Comment: Because your `mainPanel_Paint` is empty. You're not doing your painting in the Paint event at all.

Comment: I know my mainPanel_Paint is empty. The drawing portion is in mainPanel_Move

Comment: When i move the mouse very fast while drawing, the ellipses dont draw fast enough, causing the lines being drawn not to be solid.

Comment: CreateGraphics is temporary.  Minimize your form and then restore it, and your drawing will vanish.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @LarsTech What do you recommend me to do then?

Comment: See [Draw on Panel, save as Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16464669/719186)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two different problems here:

1. You are not drawing in a persistent way. Calling `CreateGraphics()` and rendering straight to the screen won't draw anything permanent. You have to draw into some type of `Image` (e.g. `Bitmap` or `Metafile`), or save the data you want to use for drawing, and then when the framework asks (via `Paint` event), use *that* to draw to the screen.
2. You are not connecting the dots. The fact is, when the user moves the mouse, you will not necessarily get adjacent points for the mouse coordinates. If the mouse is moved quickly enough, the distance between two consecutive coordinates reported can be quite large. So no matter how you draw, your ellipses may have space between them.

Consider instead code that works more like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool flag = false;
    public bool f = false;
    Bitmap panelImage;
    Point previousPoint;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

        panelImage = new Bitmap(mainPanel.Width, mainPanel.Height);
    }

    private void mainPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(panelImage, new Point());
    }

    private void mainPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        previousPoint = e.Location;
        flag = true;
    }        

    private void drawLine(Point start, Point end)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mainPanel))
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Colors.Black, 10))
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, start, end);
        }
    }

    private void mainPanel_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    private void mainPanel_move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if(flag){
        drawLine(previousPoint, e.Location);
        previousPoint = e.Location;
      }
    }
}
```

The above is just a basic example. One refinement you might make is to simply accumulate all the points, and then use `Graphics.DrawLines()` in the `mainPanel_Paint()` event handler. This would give you more control over how the lines are joined, for example.

Note also that the size of the `Bitmap` is set when the control is created; if you resize the `Panel` for some reason, the drawing area will still be the old size. Again, drawing based on a list of points would address this nicely. The downside being, of course, that as the number of lines goes up, the time it takes to redraw the panel goes up. But the `Graphics` class can easily handle thousands of lines, and depending on your PC, tens or even hundreds of thousands before you start to notice a serious slowdown.